# Pass an element of an item of an angularjs collection to javascript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this block of code

```
<ul ng-repeat="object in objects">
    ...
</ul>
```

And this function

```
<script>
    function f(a){
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Each `object` will be a list of 2 elements. I want to pass each `object` as an argument to function `f()`. 
Is there some way I can do that? Passing `object[0]` and `object[1]` as two different arguments is also an option.
I am new to angularJS and I know almost nothing about it so I can't find a solution on my own.

Comment: what should function `f` do?

Comment: object[1] actually is a string that contains json data. f() gets that and parses it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to angularjs then trying to think in angular way can help you to find solutions on your own.

In your HTML you say I have a list of objects and I want to show them as repeated unordered lists.

So the answer depends on what this function f does with each element. If it is doing something related to view then you can turn it into a filter and call with the filter syntax. If not then the best place to call it is in your controller.